# Big React Calender year view

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I need help in `react-big-calendar`.Some of the view already in `react-big-calender` like days, week & agenda etc. but how can i add custom view for year view in react-big-calender.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at the same, there is nothing out-of-the-box - I might use this as a starting point:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jjmky5047y

Answer (score 0):

You will have to customise the react-big-calendar on your own for these features.